# Product and Price Variation using Angular 9

Tags: angular

I would like to change the price of a product at the click of each button, i have 7 product variations and a price is attached to each of them. I would like to set each price as the main price when i click each button. Below is my Product.component.html code

```
                <button class="naomi" id="naomi" (click)="priceChange1($event)" *ngIf = "product.price1">{{product.three}}</button>
                <button class="naomi" id="naomi" (click)="priceChange2($event)" *ngIf = " product.price2">{{product.four}}</button>
                <button class="naomi" id="naomi" (click)="priceChange3($event)" *ngIf = "product.price3">{{product.five}}</button>
                <button class="naomi" id="naomi" (click)="priceChange4($event)" *ngIf = "product.price4">{{product.six}}</button>
                <button class="naomi" id="naomi" (click)="priceChange5($event)" *ngIf = "product.price5">{{product.seven}}</button>
                <button class="naomi" id="naomi" (click)="priceChange6($event)" *ngIf = "product.price6">{{product.seventy}}</button>
                <button class="naomi" id="naomi" (click)="priceChange7($event)" *ngIf = "product.price7">{{product.baby}}</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col-6">
                <ngb-rating [(rate)]="product.averageRating" [starTemplate]="t" [readonly]="true" max="5"></ngb-rating>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            
            <hr>
            <p class="lead">{{ product.description }}</p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <p class="lead">{{ product.specs}}</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-3 father">
            <div class="card bg-light">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Price:  ₦ {{ product.price}}  <del class=" price-old">{{product.oldprice}}</del> </h5> 
                
               
                <br>
                <br>
```

and the Products.component.ts

```
  priceChange1(event) {
  
  this.product.price === this.product.price1
  }

   priceChange2(event) {
  this.product.price === this.product.price2 
}

  priceChange3(event) {
    this.product.price === this.product.price3
  }

  public priceChange4(event) {
   this.product.price === this.product.price4  
  }

  priceChange5(event) {
  this.product.price === this.product.price5
  }

  priceChange6(event) {
    this.product.price === this.product.price6
  }

  priceChange7(event) {
    this.product.price === this.product.price7
  }
```

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't have 7 different methods, that do the same thing, you should make one method and have the parameter be the 'price#' or have the property name you want to use as a parameter.  Do you have change detection set to onPush?  Since you are mutating the object reference in Angular it may not update the UI because of that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it using only one function passing the product price in each button.

```
...
<button class="naomi" id="naomi" (click)="priceChange($event, product.price1)" *ngIf = "product.price1">{{product.three}}</button>
...
```

```
priceChange(event, newPrice) {
  this.product.price = newPrice
}
```

And maybe you must build a component to reuse the code of the button.